# How do I use undetected chromedriver to access Walmart.com?

Tags: web-scraping, undetected-chromedriver

I'm trying to use undetected chromedriver to access Walmart.com, but the default version seems to keep getting blocked by bot detection. The first time I access the website and it already show the captcha. Sometime the main page doesn't have captcha but as soon as I click to move to clearance tab for example, the captcha show up. Here is my code:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--incognito")
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get('https://www.walmart.com/')
```

Is there any options/tricks I need to use to avoid the bot detection?

Answer (score 0):

You could try https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase in UC Mode.

`pip install seleniumbase`, and run with `python`:

```py
import time
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(uc=True)
driver.get("https://www.walmart.com/")
time.sleep(3)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

(SeleniumBase includes a modified fork of undetected-chromedriver, which lets it avoid some issues.)

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work. Walmart bot detection seems very robust again these.